# Internal (Private) Android App with Subscription

Tags: java, android, subscription

I have developed an Android application which is for internal use only (my client doesn't want the app to be on Google Play)
As his request, the app should have the feature such that the application can only be used in the specific amount of time (can be various, such as 3 months, 6 months or a year, etc.) after activating an app token. After that amount of time, the app will be locked out and need another token in order to open.
I have been researching Android Private Channel with In-app purchase (or subscription) but still concerned that if it is in my case (in term of implementation simplicity, time consuming and money)
or I should create a service run on a web hosting and performs checking frequently.
I like the feature of the [Android-Subscription](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#caching) that it's already integrated the checking online and locally mechanism.
So, what do you think?

P/s: I am recently graduate student and this is my first gig :) Thank you everyone so much for your helps. I hope you have a great new year!

In case my words are not completely clear, here is basically what I want

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSiMt.png

Comment: I think you're overly complicating things.  Why worry about tokens and such for an internal app?  I'd just add a login screen, and have the server control whether the user can access it.  That way you can revoke access at any time.  Unless this isn't really an internal app and you're selling subscriptions and just trying to avoid giving Google its cut (which is fine, but you can't likely use Google Play subscriptions then).

Comment: Thanks Gabe, my client is not selling subscription, the point that implementing the subscription-like system is to monitor the user from using the app longer than their trial time. Regarding your suggestions, are there any easy ways to perform checking at startup internally and locally (because I don't want user to have to connect to the internet every time they launch the app)? I meant if the trial time is expired then the app will prompt for the new key(token)

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd have a trial time for an internal app- if the app is useful for their job why wouldn't they always have it?  But you can do that with just a login system-  have it check for expiration on login (or on every request if paranoid)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. In our case, the trial time is used to prevent people (in our case franchises) from using the app after the specific amount of time so that if they don't re-new their subscription we would count as they drop using our service and discontinue providing them the permission of using the service within the app. Other words, we don't want other people to use our app with their own services which are not directly provided from us.

Comment: After reading your comments you told that you want to check locally means prevent to connect internet every time when user launch app. so basically you need to store time in database locally which will be how much time you need to use your application. You need to fetch that time on start up your application which prevents to connect your app to internet. Finally my means you need to retrieve your data from database on start up of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you store the expiry date in a database and check that while running the app?

Comment: Thank you Akash93, I would love to have both checking locally and online as well (when the user has connected to the internet, however, most of the time they don't when they use the application). As I expect to have the user not to "cheat" the trial time by uninstall and reinstall the application or change the system date time.

Comment: You can use a local SQLite Database then . If your app is not going to have network connectivity I'm not sure how the subscription would help as well. How would it sync the time?

Comment: Thank you again, our users download (sync) data in the devices in advance, places they use it doesn't necessarily require internet connection. Therefore, I need to check even if they are not currently connecting to the internet.

Comment: Okay so what you can do is maintain an expiry date locally as well as on the server. Then whenever your app makes a network request sync this time from the server. So even if the user has changed his system time your app will not be usable.What I meant earlier was that  if your app does not have network connectivity I'm not sure that in-app billing api would be of much help either

Comment: Thanks Akash93, what is the efficient way to store the number of days the app will be remained valid? I meant I would like to store a counter and increase by 1 after 24 hours locally. How should I implement that? or simplest way to archive that task :)

Comment: Server side you'll have to use cron job to sync the expiry date on a daily basis. On client side you can use [GregorianCalendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)